# Split by a character in JavaScript but not contiguous ones

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split, contiguous

Here is the case:

```
var stringExample = "hello=goodbye==hello";
var parts = stringExample.split("=");
```

Output:

```
hello,goodbye,,hello
```

I need this Output:

```
hello,goodbye==hello
```

Contiguous / repeated characters must be ignored, just take the single `"="` to split.

Maybe some regex?

Comment: Will there always be alphanumeric characters around the `=`s that you do want to split on? Or could there be something like `hello:=!goodbye` that should be split into `hello:` and `!goodbye`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a regex :

```
var parts = stringExample.split(/\b=\b/);
```

`\b` checks for word boundaries.

Comment: I think only equality signs should be ignored, not any non-word-character.

Comment: @Bergi I'm not sure I see your problem. Can you come up with a example ?

Comment: `hello(=)goodbye` wouldn't be split in `hello(` and `)goodbye` for example - I believe that would be expected (needs clarification by the OP, please)

Comment: @Bergi OK, I see what you mean. I think we should use lookbehind for that.

Comment: @dystroy: Yeah, only that JS doesn't support lookbehind and that is what makes the task complicated :-)

Answer (score 3):

Most probably, @dystroys answer is the one you're looking for. But if any characters other than alphanumerics (`A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9` or `_`) could surround a "splitting `=`"), then his solution won't work. For example, the string

```
It's=risqué=to=use =Unicode!=See?
```

would be split into

```
"It's", "risqué=to", "use Unicode!=See?"
```

So if you need to avoid that, you would normally use a lookbehind assertion:

```
result = subject.split(/(?<!=)=(?!=)/);  // but that doesn't work in JavaScript!
```

So even though this *would* only split on single `=`s, you can't use it because JavaScript doesn't support the `(?<!...)` lookbehind assertion.

Fortunately, you can always transform a `split()` operation into a global `match()` operation by matching everything that's allowed *between*  delimiters:

```
result = subject.match(/(?:={2,}|[^=])*/g);
```

will give you

```
"It's", "risqué", "to", "use ", "Unicode!", "See?"
```

Comment: +1 I was wondering why the lookbehind in the `split` I was testing wasn't working. Is the "doesn't work in Javascript!" documented somewhere ?

Comment: @dystroy: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html is my go-to resource for this (or RegexBuddy).

Comment: `match` is usually not equivalent to a `split` in the way it handles strings beginning/ending with delimiters. Also, it could return `null`. The transformation is not trivial :-) And at least you would need to use `*` instead of `+`

Comment: @Bergi: Right, `*` it is. But I think now the result is equivalent to a (fictitious) split on the regex I mentioned above.

Answer (score -1):

As first approximation to a possible solution could be:

```
".*[^=]=[^=].*"
```

Note that this is just the regex, if you want to use it with egrep, sed, java regex or whatever, take care if something needs to be escaped.

BEWARE!: This is a first approximation, this could be improved. Note that, for instance, this regex won't match this string "=" (null - equal - null).

Comment: Can you precise how this regex should be used in OP's case ?

Comment: @dystroy `precise` isn't a verb, but looking at your profile I see you must speak French.

Comment: @dystroy I don't understand you. What OP's means?

If you are asking for an example of how to use that regex in/with a program let's see it.

The content of a file:

    hello=world
    hell0==w0rld
    bye=cruel==world
    by3==cru3l=w0rld
    =
    ==
    ===

Comment: OP wants to split a string. Can you produce, using your regex, the needed javascript code or was your answer really just a comment ?

Comment: Ok, now I realize I cannot use code blocks inside comments ¬¬. Also I have spent my 5 minutes to change the comment. Explain what you are trying to ask and I will answer you :)

Comment: a) This regex does nothing more than match an entire string that contains at least one `=` with at least one non-`=` character before and after the `=`. It doesn't do anything that would help with splitting that text into partitions. b) Even if you used capturing groups to capture the parts before and after the `=`, you could only split a string into two parts. As soon as there's more than one splitting `=`, the regex will fail.